Jupyter notebook not opening on its own, deleted anaconda and reinstalled it but the same problem... url is working but not able to launch
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.959 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\mvskv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\mvskv\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 LabApp] Extension Manager is 'pypi'.
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 ServerApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 ServerApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 ServerApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\mvskv
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.10.0 is running at:
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 ServerApp] http://localhost:8891/tree?token=411497248130a03cd3d4aa6aa8db4ed376a425ee69f2bbe0
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8891/tree?token=411497248130a03cd3d4aa6aa8db4ed376a425ee69f2bbe0
[I 2024-04-07 14:36:57.974 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2024-04-07 14:36:58.036 ServerApp]

    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/mvskv/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-10608-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8891/tree?token=411497248130a03cd3d4aa6aa8db4ed376a425ee69f2bbe0
        http://127.0.0.1:8891/tree?token=411497248130a03cd3d4aa6aa8db4ed376a425ee69f2bbe0

clicked on jupyter icon and did not open automatically
